# How to implement newinstace patterns in the fragment using a list of objects

Tags: android, android-fragments, design-patterns

How can I pass a list of objects retrieved in activity with retrofit 2, to a fragment using new instance pattern, would someone have an implementation example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your objects will need to support `Parcelable` so they can be added to a `Bundle`.  In your `Fragment`, create a static method, `newInstance` which takes your input arguments as appropriate (such as a `List` of them.)  In the `newInstance` method, create a `Bundle` and add your argument objects to it, then create an instance of your `Fragment` using `new`.  Before returning the new `Fragment` instance, call `.setArguments()` and pass it the `Bundle`.